# syspolicy_purge_history generates failed logins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a development server with 3 instances: Default, A and B.  It is 
a physical server, non clustered.  Whenever the 
syspolicy_purge_history job runs at 2 am, I get failed login alerts. 
Looking at the job steps, all are successfully completed.  It appears 
that some point during the step "Erase Phantom System Health Records" 
is when the failed logins occur.

syspolicy_purge_history on instance B works OK.

syspolicy_purge_history on the Default instance seems to want to 
connect to instance B, resulting in:

```
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11. Login failed for user 
'Machinename\sqlsvc-B'. Reason: Token-based server access validation 
failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. 
[CLIENT: <local machine>] .
```

No errors are reported by Powershell.

syspolicy_purge_history on the A instance seems to want to connect to 
the Default instance resulting in

```
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11. Login failed for user 
'Machinename\sqlsvc-Default'. Reason: Token-based server access 
validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous 
errors. [CLIENT: <local machine>] .
```

Then it tries to connect to the B instance,  resulting in

```
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11. Login failed for user 
'Machinename\sqlsvc-B'. Reason: Token-based server access validation 
failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. 
[CLIENT: <local machine>] .
```

No errors are reported by Powershell.

I tried the steps posted here hoping they would fix it. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955726  But again, this is not a 
virtual server nor is it in a cluster.  Do you have any 
suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an OS issue related to the UAC.  What OS?

Answer (score 3):

I used the workaround posted on [that Connect page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140203075148/https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/606801/syspolicy-purge-history-job) by "Kyle Neier". That worked for me.

Simply replace the PowerShell code in Step 3 of the SQL Agent Job "syspolicy_purge_history" (the one running on the default instance) with this:

```
$SQLServerConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SQLServerConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$(ESCAPE_NONE(SRVR));Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=syspolicy_purge_history"
$PolicyStoreConnection = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.SqlStoreConnection($SQLServerConnection)
$PolicyStore = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dmf.PolicyStore ($PolicyStoreConnection)
$PolicyStore.EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue a few weeks ago.

What was the result after performing Method 2 (Re-create the syspolicy_purge_history job)?

With respect to your comment "syspolicy_purge_history on the Default instance seems to want to connect to instance B", did you modify step 3 (Erase Phantom System Health Records) so that it is connecting to the DEFAULT instance and not the B instance?

Answer (score 0):

This is on Windows Server 2008.  After doing Method 2, it was the same errors.  Step 3 is showing to connect to the respective instnace.

Default Instance

```
SQLSERVER:\SQLPolicy\TEST\DEFAULT).EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords()
```

Instance A

```
SQLSERVER:\SQLPolicy\TEST\A).EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords()
```

Instance B

```
SQLSERVER:\SQLPolicy\TEST\B).EraseSystemHealthPhantomRecords()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two 2005 instances and two 2008R2 instances on one server. They have all been using NETWORK SERVICE for all services. I changed the SQL Server Agent service on one of the 2008R2 instances to use a new domain account set up specifically for that purpose. Since then, at around 2:00 AM every night, I get logon failures on the other three instances for that new service account. I have never done anything with Policy Based Management.

The workaround I found [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/606801/syspolicy-purge-history-job) seems to be to add a logon for that new domain account to the other three instances. The true fix would seem to be for Microsoft to add an option to the proc that is being called by the syspolicy_purge_history job to limit its scope to the current instance only, make that the default, and document all this somewhere other than Connect.